# .bat que elimina o nome do ficheiro deixando apenas o que está dentro de ()

Tags: windows, script, batch

Tenho um ficheiro deste género:

```
blabla_(29ago2017)_blabla
```

Preciso que fique assim:

```
(29ago2017)
```

Existe algum código em .bat que me faça este trabalho, ou seja, deixar apenas o que está dentro de parênteses como nome do ficheiro.

Answer (score 1):

Substitua .txt pela extensão correta do seus arquivos.

```batch
for %%f in (*_*_*.txt) do @(
    for /F "usebackq tokens=2,4 delims=_." %%p in ('%%f') do @( 
        ren %%f %%p.%%q
    )
)
```

Se os arquivos não possuírem extensão, então:

```batch
for %%f in (*_*_*) do @(
    for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=_." %%p in ('%%f') do @( 
        ren %%f %%p
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas execute o Script na pasta onde estão os ficheiros

```
@echo off

REM ----------------------------POR: CRISTIAN MOTA-----------------------------

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
mode 40,10
title ~    RENOMEADOR DE FICHEIROS

set line=0
echo.>%tmp%\nomes.txt
dir /b *.txt | findstr /v "nomes.txt">>%tmp%\nomes.txt
echo.fim_arq.txt>>%tmp%\nomes.txt
type "%tmp%\nomes.txt" | find /v /c "">%tmp%\quant_fich.txt
set /p quant=<%tmp%\quant_fich.txt
set /a quant=%quant%-2

:main
set /a line=%line%+1
for /f "skip=%line% tokens=* delims=(" %%R in (%tmp%\nomes.txt) do (set fich=%%R
if "!fich!" equ "fim_arq.txt" (ren "*.txt" "(*).txt"
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo.
echo.
if "%quant%" equ "1" (echo.        %quant% ficheiro foi renomeado !) else (echo.     %quant% ficheiros foram renomeados !)
echo.
echo.       FIM DA INSTRU€ÇO ! &pause >nul
exit)
set num=0
set ch=%%R
:loop1
if "!ch:~%num%,1!" neq "(" (set /a num=%num%+1 & goto loop1) Else (set ch=!ch:~%num%!
ren "!fich!" "!ch!"
goto main
)
)
```